# Añadir una linea de tendencia para cada grupo del diagrama de barras

Tags: r

Tengo una base de datos como esta:

```
             general                     Grupo   Percentage     name
        General_Men 40 - 49 years       General     5.3       Men 40 - 49 years
        General_Women 40 - 49 years     General     7.4       Women 40 - 49 years
        Episcan I_Men 40 - 49 years     Episcan I   4.7       Men 40 - 49 years
        Episcan I_Women 40 - 49 years   Episcan I   5.9       Women 40 - 49 years
        Episcan II_Men 40 - 49 years    Episcan II  6.5       Men 40 - 49 years
        Episcan II_Women 40 - 49 years  Episcan II  10.5      Women 40 - 49 years
        General_Men 50 - 59 years       General     5.1       Men 50 - 59 years
        General_Women 50 - 59 years     General     6.6       Women 50 - 59 years
        Episcan I_Men 50 - 59 years     Episcan I   10        Men 50 - 59 years
        Episcan I_Women 50 - 59 years   Episcan I   4.1       Women 50 - 59 years
        Episcan II_Men 50 - 59 years    Episcan II  1.6       Men 50 - 59 years
        Episcan II_Women 50 - 59 years  Episcan II  10.7      Women 50 - 59 years
        General_Men 60 - 69 years       General     11.1      Men 60 - 69 years
        General_Women 60 - 69 years     General     4.8       Women 60 - 69 years
        Episcan I_Men 60 - 69 years     Episcan I   11.7      Men 60 - 69 years
        Episcan I_Women 60 - 69 years   Episcan I   4.7       Women 60 - 69 years
        Episcan II_Men 60 - 69 years    Episcan II  10.4      Men 60 - 69 years
        Episcan II_Women 60 - 69 years  Episcan II  5         Women 60 - 69 years
        General_Men 70 - 79 years       General     16.5      Men 70 - 79 years
        General_Women 70 - 79 years     General       9       Women 70 - 79 years
        Episcan I_Men 70 - 79 years     Episcan I   25.5      Men 70 - 79 years
        Episcan I_Women 70 - 79 years   Episcan I   4.6       Women 70 - 79 years
        Episcan II_Men 70 - 79 years    Episcan II  6.5       Men 70 - 79 years
        Episcan II_Women 70 - 79 years  Episcan II  15.2      Women 70 - 79 years
        General_Men = 80 years          General       25      Men = 80 years
        General_Women = 80 years        General      5.6      Women = 80 years
        Episcan I_Men = 80 years        Episcan I   0         Men = 80 years
        Episcan I_Women = 80 years      Episcan I   0         Women = 80 years
        Episcan II_Men = 80 years       Episcan II  25        Men = 80 years
        Episcan II_Women = 80 years     Episcan II  5.6       Women = 80 years
```

El cual quiero ver cual es la tendencia que existe entre los diferentes grupos:
Para ello he realizado un diagrama de barras al que le he querido añadir una linea de tendencia para cada grupo junto con los números a los que les corresponde.

Ejecuté el siguiente código:

```
 ggplot(data2, aes(fill=Grupo, y=Percentage, x=name)) + 
   geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+ 
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1),
         panel.background = element_blank(),axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
   scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0.5),limits=c(0,30))+
   geom_point(data = data2, aes(name, Percentage), color = "blue")+
   geom_line(data = data2, aes(name, Percentage), group = 1, color = "blue") +
   geom_text(data = data2, 
             aes( y = Percentage, label = Percentage )) + 
   labs(x = "Sex and age range", y="Percentage (%)")  +
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("#596fb0", "#9fb059","#edae52"))
```

Generé un diagrama de barras pero no pude añadirle las tres lineas de tendencia, una para cada grupo, y los números junto con puntos aparecen todos juntos para el grupo del medio en vez de para cada grupo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas, al menos en este caso, reconfigurar los datos en cada `geom_()`, igual pasa con las estéticas, casi todo ya está configurado de forma global con `ggplot(...)`. Únicamente para el `geom_line()` habría que agregar la estética `group` para poder generar las tres líneas por cada grupo y la de `color` para hacer consistente el color de los puntos y la líneas con el de las barras. Por último, agregamos un `scale_color_manual()` para mantener el mismo color de `fill`. Y al `geom_text()` lo configuramos en negro, para destacar las etiquetas

```
library(tidyverse)

colores <- c("#596fb0", "#9fb059","#edae52"
ggplot(data2, aes(fill=Grupo, y=Percentage, x=name, colour=Grupo, group=Grupo)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1),
        panel.background = element_blank(),axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0.5),limits=c(0,30) )+
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Percentage), color="black") + 
  labs(x = "Sex and age range", y="Percentage (%)")  +
  scale_fill_manual(values=colores) +
  scale_color_manual(values=colores)
```

Si quieres ajustar la posición de de puntos, lineas y texto a cada barra, simplemente hay que agregar a las estéticas `position = position_dodge(width = ancho)`

```
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_line(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Percentage), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), color="black") +
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Patricio por tu pronta respuesta. Sien embargo los valores que arroja en la gráfica todos los situa en las barras de Episcan II y no en general o episcan I y por otro lado, ¿se podrían poner un poco más arriba del gráfico las lineas? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cheque mi última edición. Saludos.

Comment: Funciona a la perfección, gracias Patricio por tu pronta respuesta